# Async WCF Call in mono stucks in endless loop

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin, xamarin.android

i have a Problem in MonoAndroid calling a WCF Service async.
I followed this Tutorial and created the Portable Class Lib. http://nullskull.com/a/10476775/xamarin-cross-platform-application-consuming-wcf--part-1.aspx

Here is my Service Method which is calling the WCF Service:

```
public async static Task<KeyExchangeModel> GetPublicKeyFromServer(KeyExchangeModel model)
{
    try
    {
        ISyncService client;
        client = new SyncServiceClient(_binding, _endpointAddress);

        var res = Task<KeyExchangeModel>.Factory.FromAsync(client.BeginGetServerPublicKey, client.EndGetServerPublicKey,
                model, null);
        await res;
        return res.Result;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }   
}
```

An here i call the Method and wait till it´s executed.

```
Task<KeyExchangeModel> task = SyncServiceAgent.GetPublicKeyFromServer(keyModel);
task.Wait();
KeyExchangeModel serverModel = task.Result;
```

The Problem is that on Android i never get the Result. It stuck´s in a Loop. No Exception is logged in the Device Log or is thrown.

This code Perfectly works on a Windows Unit Test and on a Windows Phone Project.

I hope anyone can help me.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line here: `task.Wait();` Blocking on asynchronous code can cause deadlocks.

By default, `await` will capture the current "context", and use that context to resume the `async` method. In this case, it's probably capturing the UI context, which is tied to the UI thread. So, `GetPublicKeyFromServer` will start the WCF call, capture the UI context, and return an incomplete task. The calling code then calls `Task.Wait` on that task, which *blocks* the UI thread until that async method completes.

Later, the WCF call returns, and `GetPublicKeyFromServer` attempts to resume in the same context (on the UI thread). However, the UI thread is blocked waiting for `GetPublicKeyFromServer` to complete. This is a classic deadlock situation.

The reason it work in a unit test is because the `async` method captures a thread pool context instead of the UI context, so it is able to block one thread pool thread in the `Wait` and *another* thread pool thread can complete the `async` method. Normally, a Windows Phone app would have the same problem with UI context as the Android app, so I suspect that there's something different with the test code, and that's why it's not deadlocking on WP.

I describe this problem in more detail [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), [in an MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx), and [in my book](http://tinyurl.com/ConcurrencyCookbook).

The best resolution for this problem is to use `await` instead of `Task.Wait` or `Task<T>.Result`. I.e., your calling code should be:

```
Task<KeyExchangeModel> task = SyncServiceAgent.GetPublicKeyFromServer(keyModel);
KeyExchangeModel serverModel = await task;
```

This will require your calling code to be `async`, which in turn requires *its* callers to be `async`, etc. This "growth" of async through the codebase is natural and normal.